# Trying to create a Parse function for my String ADT using LogEntry C++

Tags: c++, string, parsing, adt

```
std::vector<LogEntry> parse(std::istream& in) {
    std::vector<LogEntry> result;

    char c[500];
    LogEntry log;
    String entry;
    while(!in.eof()){
      in.getline(c, 500);
      if(in.eof())
        break;
      entry = String(c);
      log = LogEntry(entry);
      result.push_back(log);
    }
return result;
}
```

How do I change this parse function for it to work I have print out statements in my code and it stops at entry = String(c), our goal with this function is to use our String ADT we created and to read all the lines from the files that they give us and to create a logEntry object for each line. This function will return a vector of logEntry's.

Comment: What is `String`, what is `LogEntry` and how do you know that it stops at the line you mentioned? Please provide some more information.

Comment: please provide a [mre] with sample input and exactly what the issue is that you are having

Comment: Probably beside the question, but you can clean up the end-of-file logic. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c. No need to check EOF twice.

Comment: `while (in.getline(c, 500)` is a better loop.

Comment: At a guess, `String` should obey "the rule of three (or five)" but doesn't.

Comment: It looks like you could slim that down to `while (in.getline(c, 500)) { result.push_back(String(c)); }`.